# Can I include headers inside form-groups?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know if its OK for me to include a header/s (h1) inside a form-group? I have added a simple form to the snippet for an example.

I am not super clear on if I can or cannot include it in this way? Just want to make sure I am doing it correctly.

The reason why I am doing it like this, is because the headers align perfectly flush with left-hand side of the form, otherwise nesting them outside the form-group makes them sit further to the left.

So, are they similar to the legend property in a form if I wish to use headers instead?

Cheers!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <h1>Form details</h1>
        <h4>Please fill out this form</h4>

        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay, but not good for SEO, you miss h2 and h3 header between your headers

Comment: I know, I only used h1 and h4 for size difference...but thanks for clearing the question up for me! :)